# How to percolate simple_query_string/query_string query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-percolate

Index:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index.percolator.map_unmapped_fields_as_text": true,
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "query": {
                "type": "percolator"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This test percolator query works

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "message": "blah"
        }
    }
}
```

This query doesn't work

```
{
    "query": {
        "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "bl*"
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
{"took":15,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":1,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":0.13076457,"hits":[{"_index":"my-index","_type":"_doc","_id":"1","_score":0.13076457,"_source":{"query":{"match":{"message":"blah"}}},"fields":{"_percolator_document_slot":[0]}}]}}
```

Why this simple_query_string query doesn't match the document ?

Comment: What exactly is your question? do you have an example of what's not working?

Comment: The question is how to unit percolator index to work with simple_query_string queries. Or how to insert simple_query_string into a percolator index. Basically I’m looking for a working example.

Comment: Your last query `{ "query": { "simple_query_string": {"query": "blah"}, "analyzer" : "my_analyzer" } }` errors out because it is not valid, it should be `{ "query": { "simple_query_string": {"query": "blah", "analyzer" : "my_analyzer" } } }`

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what you are asking either. It may be that you do not understand percolator very well?
This is an example I just tried now.

Let's assume you have an index - let's call it `test` - in which you want to index some documents. This index has the following mapping (just a random test index I have in my test setup):

```
{  
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "email": {
              "type": "pattern_capture",
              "preserve_original": true,
              "patterns": [
                "([^@]+)",
                "(\\p{L}+)",
                "(\\d+)",
                "@(.+)",
                "([^-@]+)"
              ]
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "email": {
              "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
              "filter": [
                "email",
                "lowercase",
                "unique"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "code": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "date": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "part": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "val": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "email": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "email"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You notice it has a custom `email` analyzer that splits something like `foo@bar.com` into these tokens: `foo@bar.com`, `foo`, `bar.com`, `bar`, `com`.

As the documentation says, you could create a separate percolator index that will hold only your percolator queries, not also the documents themselves. And, even if the percolator index doesn't contain the documents themselves, it should hold the mapping of the index that should hold the documents (`test` in our case).

This is the mapping of the percolator index (which I called it `percolator_index`) that also has the special analyzer used for splitting the `email` field:

```
{  
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "email": {
              "type": "pattern_capture",
              "preserve_original": true,
              "patterns": [
                "([^@]+)",
                "(\\p{L}+)",
                "(\\d+)",
                "@(.+)",
                "([^-@]+)"
              ]
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "email": {
              "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
              "filter": [
                "email",
                "lowercase",
                "unique"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "query": {
                "type": "percolator"
            },
            "code": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "date": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "part": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "val": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "email": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "email"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its mapping and settings are almost the same with my original index, the only difference being the additional `query` field which is of type `percolator` added to the mapping.

The query you are interested it - `simple_query_string` - should go into a document inside `percolator_index`. Like so:

```
PUT /percolator_index/_doc/1?refresh
{
    "query": {
        "simple_query_string" : {
            "query" : "month foo@bar.com",
            "fields": ["part", "email"]
        }
    }
}
```

To make it more interesting, I added the `email` field in there to be specifically searched for in the query (by default, all of them are searched).

Now, the aim is to test a document that should eventually go into `test` index against this `simple_query_string` query from your percolator index. For example:

```
GET /percolator_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "percolate": {
      "field": "query",
      "document": {
        "date":"2004-07-31T11:57:52.000Z","part":"month","code":109,"val":0,"email":"foo@bar.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What's under `document` is, obviously, your future (non-existent yet) document. This will be matched against the above defined `simple_query_string` and will result in a match:

```
{
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.39324823,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "percolator_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.39324823,
                "_source": {
                    "query": {
                        "simple_query_string": {
                            "query": "month foo@bar.com",
                            "fields": [
                                "part",
                                "email"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "fields": {
                    "_percolator_document_slot": [
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What if I would have percolated this document instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "percolate": {
      "field": "query",
      "document": {
        "date":"2004-07-31T11:57:52.000Z","part":"month","code":109,"val":0,"email":"foo"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(notice that the email is only `foo`)
This is the result:

```
{
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.26152915,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "percolator_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.26152915,
                "_source": {
                    "query": {
                        "simple_query_string": {
                            "query": "month foo@bar.com",
                            "fields": [
                                "part",
                                "email"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "fields": {
                    "_percolator_document_slot": [
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Notice that the score is a bit lower than the first percolated document. This is probably like this because `foo` (my email) matched only one of the terms inside my analyzed `foo@bar.com`, while `foo@bar.com` would have matched all of them (thus giving a better score)

Not sure what analyzer are you talking about though. I think the example above covers the only "analyzer" issue/unknown that I think may be a bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer Andrei, but my problem is a little bit different. The simple_query_string from my example doesn't look for a specific field, instead it looks across the all fields in the document. So, I'm looking how to make this cross field query to work under percolator.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. You can remove the `fields` part from the query def. The point is that it's about how you structure your index and what analyzers you define for your fields (I just provided a bit more complex example with an `email` custom analyzer), and not about the percolator. The percolator is just a way to run a document through a set of defined queries (your `simple_query_string`). Defining the mappings for the fields used in the document should be done like the percolator wouldn't even be used. Can you explain a bit more, please? I still don't see an issue here, sorry.

Comment: May I suggest one more thing: play with `simple_query_string` just like you would do if percolator would not be in the picture. Like, using an `analyzer` to analyze the text provided to `simple_query_string`. And when you are done coming up with the final query and the final mapping for your index, move that to a percolator.

Comment: I've updated the question with an actual simple_query_string example which doesn't work.

Comment: Now I understand the actual issue you have. Let me look into it.

Comment: FYI, I created https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/48874 because there is either an undocumented issue or a bug in itself.

Comment: Thank you Andrei, this was really helpful, I hope you guys will sort this out.